# Comparing with datetime

Tags: php, datetime

In a database I have stored items with a date. stored as timestamp.

I want to use the date (not the time) to find more products in the table with the same date.

I'm new to thee datetime calcullation.
I thought this would be the best way:

```
//orginal date
$changeddate = new datetime( '2015-01-03 19:27:52');
$orgdate = $changeddate->format('d-m-Y');

//date in the database
$moredates = new DateTime( '2015-01-03 12:22:12' );
$moredate = $moredates->format('d-m-Y');

if ($orgdate === $moredate ) {
//date is the same
}else{
//date is not the same
}
```

I choose === because it is better to use identical instead of equal.

The script is working fine, but I was thinking there might be a nicer way to do this.

Comment: Which language is that?

Comment: So your not doing all in the database e.g 1 select, instead your selecting all looping and then comparing the result set with the "original date"?

Comment: Yes, but I think it will become very slow with many items. Now there only 32 items, but in the end there will be about 400 items max.

Comment: Pass the original date to sql an let sql do the grunt, its faster then doing it in php. sql has plenty of date functions that can "round" your date to match days ect http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html